# How can I extract broken off shutter-lok fasteners from brick?

Tags: drill, brick, ladder, shutters

I'm in the process of replacing vinyl shutters on my brick-front home.  I'm replacing the existing ones with identical sized new ones that will use the same drilled holes.  The problem I'm having is that when I take off the old shutters the old [shutter-lok](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Shutter-Lok) fasteners often break off with nothing to grab on to.  At ground level I have been able to drill them out by pressing with all my body weight while drilling.  I can't do this for the higher ones since I have to be on a ladder.  Is there a effective tool I can use to extract these plastic fasteners from the pre-drilled holes in the brick without applying significant force?

Note: I have tried using smaller drill bits to break it up first with limited success.  I have also tried a reverse-thread screw extraction bit that didn't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to take a long wood screw, drill it into the plastic fastener that is stuck in the wall, then take a hammer and pry it back out - hopefully with most of the plastic fastener still attached.  It isn't great, but the best I can do until I find a better method.